# NullPointerException with a method that has an interface return type

Tags: java, interface, nullpointerexception

I've an interface that goes like this -

```
public interface IntSequence {
 int length();
 int get(int index);
 void set(int index, int value);
  /**
  * Returns a contiguous subsequence of size "size" which starts from
  * the index "index" and is backed by the sequence;
  * that is, changing it through {@link IntSequence#set(int, int)}
  * affects the original sequence as well.
  * @param index the starting position of the subsequence
  * @param size the subsequence size
  * @return a sequence of ints
  */
 IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size);
}
```

And a class in that implements it which goes like this -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class IntArray implements IntSequence {

    int[] a;
    int use;
    ArrayList<Integer> valuelist1 = new ArrayList<>();

    public IntArray(int size) {
        a = new int[size];
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
        return a.length;
    }

    @Override
    public int get(int index) {
        use = a[index];
        return use;
    }

    @Override
    public void set(int index, int value) {
        a[index] = value;
    }

    public IntArray(int index, int size, int[] array) {
        for(int i = index; i <= (size + index); i++)
        {
            if(i >= array.length)
                break;
            else
                valuelist1.add(array[i]);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size) {
        IntSequence resultseq = new IntArray(index, size, a);
        return resultseq;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IntSequence a = new IntArray(5);
        a.set(0, 0);
        a.set(1, 10);
        a.set(2, 20);
        a.set(3, 30);
        a.set(4, 40);


        System.out.println("Initial array");
        System.out.println("size: " + a.length());
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            System.out.println("a[" + i + "]: " + a.get(i));

        System.out.println("Creating subarray (2, 2)");
        IntSequence s = a.subSequence(2, 2);

        System.out.println("s.size: " + s.length());

        System.out.println("Multiplying subarray's last element");
        s.set(1, s.get(1) * 10);
        System.out.println("Subarray after modification:");
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); ++i)
            System.out.println("s[" + i + "]: " + s.get(i));

        System.out.println("Array after modification:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
            System.out.println("a[" + i + "]: " + a.get(i));

        a.subSequence(0, 1).subSequence(0, 1).subSequence(0, 1).set(0, -10);
        System.out.println("First element changed to: " + a.get(0));
    }


}
```

**PROBLEM** - My issue here is with the method `IntSequence subSequence(int index, int size)` as I am not allowed to change the type of subSequence and the solution that I have came up for this that is making a new constructor `IntArray(int index, int size, int[] array)` , using it in the subSequence and returning it returns a null value hence getting a NullPointerException when I try to run the program.

Thank you for looking at my issue!

Comment: I am not sure how you call these methods but, it seems that you forgot to initialize array in your second constructor.

Comment: @EnginKayraklioglu That is what I was thinking but I am not sure that is it. Still it is interesting the a reference is not given an array object to point to.

Comment: Exception should show the exact line of exception, that might help solve the problem. And your code is unnecessarily complicated, you pass the class member array to the constructor? Why? Can't you just create a method that creates an IntArray with the first constructor, fills it accordingly and returns it. It sounds neater.

Comment: Why do you have both `valuelist` and `a`?  I don't see a reason you need both.

Answer (score 1):

You're not initializing the value of `int[] a` in your second constructor as you do in first one:

```
public IntArray(int size) {
    //int[] a is initialized
    a = new int[size];
}
public IntArray(int index, int size, int[] array) {
    //int[] a is never initialized
    for(int i = index; i <= (size + index); i++) {
        if(i >= array.length)
            break;
        else
            valuelist1.add(array[i]);
    }
}
```

I recommend you just calling the constructor that initializes your array in the second constructor:

```
public IntArray(int index, int size, int[] array) {
    //line below invokes constructor with 1 argument
    this(size);
    for(int i = index; i <= (size + index); i++) {
        if(i >= array.length)
            break;
        else
            valuelist1.add(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Apart from this problem, you should add the values of `int[] array` into `int[] a` in your second constructor (just an opinion) and use better names for your variables

Comment: Nice job.  I did not think of calling the first constructor with this `this` keyword. Now it works on my machine too.

Comment: Are you sure it gives you the right results?  This constructor puts data in `valuelist1`, but I don't see anywhere where that data is ever used.  (Another small point: `this(size)` may not be correct.  If you hit the `break` statement, you won't have `size` elements in your array.  You may need `this(Math.min(size,[something else]))` or a different approach.)

Comment: @ajb I only tried to solve the `NullPointerException`. Below the solution of this problem, added a comment explaining that it would be better adding the elements inside this `int[] a` array instead of `valuelist1`. What OP really tries to achieve, is a mistery.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza my comment was intended for the OP, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

int[]a is not initialised, if you can't initialise the variable before calling the method I would recommend using overloaded versions of the method that cover the optional parameters, although depending on how many optional parameters you have, this could get messy.

Java doesn't support default parameters